# Can we always find field extensions of a given number field and a given degree?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Given a finite extension $F/\mathbb{Q}$, and given $n$, can we always find an extension $K/F$ of degree $n$? If so, is there an explicit way to construct one?

Comment: Eisenstein criterion applied to any prime number unramified in $F$.

Comment: Is there a way to see this without algebraic number theoretic language? My background for this is anything covered in a first course in field/Galois theory and, if needed, a first course in commutative algebra (primary decompositions of ideals, integral extensions etc. but not much about e.g. Krull dimension).

Let's say I consider all polynomials $x^n-p$, why can't it be the case that they are all somehow reducible (not necessarily split into linear factors) over $F$?

Comment: Try this: let the degree of $F$ be $r$. $F$ has only finitely many roots of unity. Choose $m$ so that the degree of $\zeta_m$ over the rationals is a multiple of $nr$ (here, $\zeta_m=e^{2\pi i/m}$). Let $L$ be the extension of $F$ generated by $\zeta_m$. Show that $L$ has a subfield $K$ of degree $n$ over $F$.

Comment: Otherwise do you know that $x^{p^k}-2\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible for all $k$? If so then you can take the largest $k$ such that it has a root $a$ in $F$. Then $x^p-a\in F[x]$ is irreducible (because otherwise an irreducible factor $f$ of it would be such that $f(0) =(-1)^j\zeta_p^m a^{j/p}$, with $jl=1\bmod p$ you'd get that $(-1)^{jl} f(0)^l p^{-(jl-1)/p} \in F$ is a root of $x^p-a$). You've constructed an extension of degree $p$ arbitrary so you can construct a tower of extensions of degree $n$. @GerryMyerson

Comment: Thank you both. @reuns , your second comment works for me, if you'd like to post it as an answer I'd be glad to accept it. (Also just to make sure - it should be $(-1)^{jl}f(0)^la^{-(jl-1)/p}$ instead of $p$ in the base, right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p$ prime, once you know that  $x^{p^k}−2\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible for all $k$ (or just that $\bigcup_k \Bbb{Q}(2^{1/p^k})$ is not a finite extension),

take the largest $k$ such that $x^{p^k}-2$ has a root $a$ in $F$. You'll get that $x^p−a\in F[x]$ is irreducible.

> Proof: assuming it is reducible, with an irreducible factor $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^j(x-a^{1/p}\zeta_p^{c_i})$ and $jl=1+mp$ you'll get that $(−1)^{jl} f(0)^l a^{-m}= \zeta_p^{l\sum_{i=1}^j c_i} a^{1/p}\in F$ is a root of $x^p-a$, contradicting that $k$ is the largest.

You've constructed an extension $F(a^{1/p})/F$ of degree $p$ arbitrary so you can construct a tower of extensions of degree $n$.